# How to skip dirty checking overhead when merging JPA/Hibernate cached entity?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity which holds hundreds of thousands of entities on its collections, all of them persisted and already eagerly fetched earlier on the application. Nonetheless on every transaction it takes up to twenty minutes to merge the single "top-entity" back to the new injected entity manager (I'm using Spring for the I-o-C). In my application I can assume there is no concurrency therefore I could skip the dirty-checking which is what I presume is what is causing the lag. I removed the @Version annotations from all the entities assuming that would change from optimistic lock to "NONE" lock but that didn't help.

Besides that, the JDBC connection configuration is read-commited. I am using a mix of JPA, Hibernate and Spring annotations.

The version of Hibernate is 5.0, the DB is Postgres 9.5 and the Spring Container is 4.2 and the Servlet Container is Tomcat 8.

I need to merge this entity back without doing any kind of dirty-checking. Maybe, the only way to go is with Extended Persistence Context, but that would be very ugly because we are not talking about an Stateful Bean but about an entire application.

Any ideas?